# Unable to run simple presto shell query

Tags: sql, bash, hive, presto, trino

I am trying to run simplest query.
However it is not working.

```
-bash-4.2$ prestosql --execute "select 1;"
Exception in thread "main" io.airlift.airline.ParseArgumentsUnexpectedException: Found unexpected parameters: [1;]
    at io.airlift.airline.SingleCommand.validate(SingleCommand.java:98)
    at io.airlift.airline.SingleCommand.parse(SingleCommand.java:65)
    at io.airlift.airline.SingleCommand.parse(SingleCommand.java:56)
    at io.prestosql.cli.Presto.main(Presto.java:24)
```

But --file option works fine

```
-bash-4.2$ cat a.sql
select 1;
-bash-4.2$ prestosql --file a.sql > result
-bash-4.2$ cat result
"1"
```

Any ideas?
UPD:
Trying to escape ';' with backslash doesn't help(

```
-bash-4.2$ prestosql --execute "select 1"
Exception in thread "main" io.airlift.airline.ParseArgumentsUnexpectedException: Found unexpected parameters: [1]
    at io.airlift.airline.SingleCommand.validate(SingleCommand.java:98)
    at io.airlift.airline.SingleCommand.parse(SingleCommand.java:65)
    at io.airlift.airline.SingleCommand.parse(SingleCommand.java:56)
    at io.prestosql.cli.Presto.main(Presto.java:24)
-bash-4.2$ prestosql --execute "select 1\;"
Exception in thread "main" io.airlift.airline.ParseArgumentsUnexpectedException: Found unexpected parameters: [1\;]
    at io.airlift.airline.SingleCommand.validate(SingleCommand.java:98)
    at io.airlift.airline.SingleCommand.parse(SingleCommand.java:65)
    at io.airlift.airline.SingleCommand.parse(SingleCommand.java:56)
    at io.prestosql.cli.Presto.main(Presto.java:24)
```

Comment: Is `prestosql` your wrapper or the presto-cli executable jar itself? If it's a wrapper, do you use e.g. `$*` in it?

Comment: Yes it's wrapper for presto-cli.jar and it's using $@ at the end

Comment: However replacing $@ with $* doesn't help(((

Comment: `$@` should be wrapped in quotes: `"$@"` (this is the idiomatic way of passing args in a wrapper). I guess `"` are missing, correct?

Comment: You are absolutely rigth! Thank you!

Comment: Added this as an answer, so you can accept. BTW please join the [Presto community slack](https://prestosql.io/slack.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be an issue with the wrapper around presto CLI executable jar.

The wrapper script needs to use `"$@"` to preserve parameter with spaces (like the SQL query being passed to `--execute`).

Note: there is usually no need to have a wrapper script for CLI executable. It's executable, so you can place it directly on `$PATH`. (Or, place a symlink on path)

Answer (score 1):

Try the same without semicolon `;` or shield semicolon with `\`:

```
 prestosql --execute "select 1"
```

or

```
 prestosql --execute "select 1\;"
```